# How to wipe out elasticsearch local node?

Tags: elasticsearch

I'm using local nodes for testing (I know about `elasticsearch-test` but don't see how it can be used when the client is dependency injected) and each time I run the test, the count increments. What I really want is for the Node to start fresh each time. How can this be done?

It looks like I can wipe out the `data/elasticsearch` directory but was hoping for a more elegant solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can fire a DeleteIndex query when starting the test.

But I found that cleaning dir is fine. See https://github.com/elasticsearchfr/hands-on/blob/answers/src/test/java/org/elasticsearchfr/handson/StartNode.java#L21